# command line IntelliJ on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I'm trying to launch IntelliJ on command line in Mac OS X to use it's diff tool.  Theoretically `idea.sh diff file1 file2` should work.  In practice there are some issues with the file which I think I worked around (removing some arguments to readlink etc).
However when it does start, it wants me to enter license information (even though an instance of Intellij is already running and the license is there).  Which leads me to believe that there is some sort of separation of command line world vs non-command line world on Mac OS X?  IS that true?
Also when I select 30 days eval it proceeds to give me the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/fileEditor/impl/FileEditorProviderManagerImpl.getProviders must not be null
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorProviderManagerImpl.getProviders(FileEditorProviderManagerImpl.java)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.highlighting.EditorPlaceHolder.setContent(EditorPlaceHolder.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.highlighting.DiffPanelState$1.run(DiffPanelState.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:864)
...
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try running `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea` instead. `idea.sh` is not designed for Mac and will not work without some manual changes.

Another option is to create the command line launcher: Tools | Create Command-line Launcher.

If you are using [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/), it provides the way to create the command launcher automatically.

Comment: It's better - no license issues, but it still gives me the same error (in a dialog box now): Error showing diff: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/fileEditor/impl/FileEditorProviderManagerImpl.getProviders must not be null

Comment: so this works for diff, but I would like to invoke the merging functionality (be able to save after resolving conflicts).  Is this doable?

Comment: No, merge is not possible yet, please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-69292.

Comment: what is the setup so you can start it from any directory with the following:  idea .

Comment: Is there a way to open a file in a new tab via command line functionality rather than a new instance of Intellij?

Answer (score 196):

IntelliJ can install a command line launcher for you, adding it to a PATH directory would make it as any other commands on the system. The command is "idea".

[image: IntelliJ Command-line Launcher]

Answer (score 35):

Try:

**Tools > Create Commandline Launcher**

This will create a command line launcher.
After that you can launch IntelliJ from your desired folder like with a command like this :

```
idea .
```

or

```
idea <path to the folder>
```

Answer (score 15):

First step, you'll follow and click the menu, **Tools > Create Commandline Launcher**  you'll run this command on what you want open project's directory.

```
idea .
```

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question that has answers already it is useful to explain why your answer is different. Can you edit your answer to  explain how it differs from the one by Meeh, and how your answer addresses the diff portion of the question?

Comment: Awesome, should be a answer

Answer (score 9):

If you have the toolbox installed, this is now controlled using the Toolbox App Settings.

### First enable using the (global) toolbox app settings:

[image]

### Now, you can enable at the IDE level (here using Intellij):

[image]

Comment: But need to log in to your JetBrains Account!

Comment: I needed to restart the toolbox to see IDE level settings.

Answer (score 6):

Idea expects paths to be fully qualified, so I wrote a small helper script. Invoke like:

```
$ idiff foo.txt bar.txt
```

The code for `idiff`:

```
#!/bin/bash
idea='/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 10.app/Contents/MacOS/idea'
left=`abspath $1`
right=`abspath $2`
"$idea" diff $left $right
```

There is probably a real `abspath` tool somewhere, but I have a simple hand-rolled one:

```
$ cat `which abspath`
#!/bin/bash
ORIG_DIR=`pwd`
for fn in $* ; do 
  if [ -e $fn ]; then
    d=`dirname $fn`
    if [ -z $d ]; then 
      echo `pwd`/$fn
    else
      cd $d
      echo `pwd`"/"`basename $fn`
    fi
  else
    echo "Don't know how to process $fn" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
  cd $ORIG_DIR
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested for the new versions of IntelliJ in 2023: -

add this line in .zhsrc:

```
alias idea="/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea"
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must create the shell scripts to open the IDEs, in the latest version it's done on the Toolbox

```
Toolbox App > Configuration > Settings > Generate shell script > export to a folder like /User/asilva/IDEs
```

Then you could call it like `./User/asilva/IDEs/idea` or `./User/asilva/IDEs/webstorm`

But if you want to call it without the absolute path, the it's needed to add it on the $PATH to be loaded every time the terminal is open:

```
~/.zshrc

(...)

# idea + webstorm
export PATH="/Users/asilva/IDEs:$PATH"
```

with this, the `webstorm` or `idea` command will be globally available

Answer (score 0):

In the case of PHPStorm, you need to do the same - **`Tools > Create Commandline Launcher`** but inside Terminal you should use `pstorm .`