# git-lfs command not found webstorm

Tags: git, webstorm, git-lfs

I use WebStorm and after adding git-lfs I started to get this error[image]

> Error updating changes: git-lfs filter-process: git-lfs: command not found the remote end hung up unexpectedly

It prevents git updates. Lfs is working fine in every terminal.

Comment: The same on WebStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009490059-git-lfs-command-not-found-webstorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like git-lfs is not on your $PATH when running the IDE from Finder, etc.

On MacOSX the environment variables differ between GUI applications and within the terminal. Terminal environment is only available to applications started from terminal. To solve this problem, WebStorm tries to load terminal environment by executing the following command on startup:

-l -i -c '/Applications/webstorm.app/bin/printenv.py'

Seems this command can't retrieve all needed stuff in your case - thus the issue.

Some links you may find useful: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications.. The problem is that the way to define system-wide environment variables on Mac changes from one version to another (even minor system updates may break your environment)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ. In my case, I could not solve my problem via the confirmed answer.

However, I have no error **opening the IDE from the terminal**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836740/3202266

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

For me (Mac M1), quitting and restarting PyCharm completely (not only a single Project) fixed the problem.

Comment: correct.  use homebrew to manage the git.  
`git` and `git-lfs` both under  `/opt/homebrew/bin/`